# Spring Boot + Oracle: Hibernate dialect is 9i when in properties it is set to 10g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot app with an Oracle DB and I specifically set the `spring.datasource.platform` value to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`.

During runtime I see this message:

```
2017-03-30 14:15:34.474  INFO 6664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
```

Why is it showing 9i instead of 10g? Is this something that I am doing wrong, or is this being forced on by my driver version in the pom, or by the  database that I am using?

This is the pom driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try with the below property key?

```
spring.jpa.database-platform
```

For more info 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties